# How to perform pop() and shift() function in alternating order in an JavaScript and add that popped and shifted element to another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Expected Output:
First array: A
Second array: B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I
Resulting array: A,I,B,H,C,G,D,F,E

I have tried the below code but can't seem to get the expected output. It works just fine but the loop seems to be missing the two last elements of the expected output. It works just fine for elements with smaller length though.

Code:

```
var array1 = ["A"];
var array2 = ["B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"];
var string1 = '';
    var string2 = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length ; i++){
        if(string1 === ''){
            string1 = array1[i];
        }else{
            string1 = string1 + "," + array1[i];
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
        if(string2 === ''){
            string2 = array2[i];
        }else{
            string2 = string2 + "," + array2[i];
        }
    }
    console.log("First array: " + string1);
    console.log("Second array: " + string2);
    
    for (var i = 0; i <= array2.length; i++){
        var removedLast = array2.pop();
        if(removedLast !== undefined){
            array1.push(removedLast);
        }
        var removedFirst = array2.shift();
        if(removedFirst !== undefined){
            array1.push(removedFirst);
        }
    }
    
    string1 = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
        if(string1 === ''){
            string1 = array1[i];
        }else{
            string1 = string1 + "," + array1[i];
        }
    }
    
    console.log("Resulting array: " + string1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pop and shift are modifying the length of the array as your performing these.  For the for loop where you are popping and shifting, change it from i++ to just i.  Else save off the length of the array into another variable and use that as your limit in the for loop.

Like this

```
    var timesToLoop = array2.length / 2;
    for (var i = 0; i < timesToLoop; i++){
        var removedLast = array2.pop();
        if(removedLast !== undefined){
            array1.push(removedLast);
        }
        var removedFirst = array2.shift();
        if(removedFirst !== undefined){
            array1.push(removedFirst);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, is a cleaner solution, just loop the array and take advantage of the "%" operator to decide which method you'll use.

```js
const array1 = ["A"];
const array2 = ["B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"];
const result = []

//First element of array1
result.push(array1.shift())

//Number of iterations
const startLength = array2.length

for(let i = 0; i<startLength; i++){
  //Check if the iteration number is even or odd, then use pop or shift method
  result.push(i%2==0?array2.pop():array2.shift())
}

console.dir(result)
```

Run the code snippet to see the result

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working properly because when we look with console log,

```
var array1 = ["A"];
var array2 = ["B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"];
var string1 = array1.join(',');
var string2 = array2.join(',');
console.log("First array: " + string1);
console.log("Second array: " + string2);

for (var i = 0; i <= array2.length; i++){
    console.log("Step1:", array2.length, i);
    var removedLast = array2.pop();
    if(removedLast !== undefined){
        array1.push(removedLast);
    }
    console.log("Step2:", array2.length, i);;
    var removedFirst = array2.shift();
    if(removedFirst !== undefined){
        array1.push(removedFirst);
    }
    console.log("Step3:", array2.length, i);
}

string1 = '';
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
    if(string1 === ''){
        string1 = array1[i];
    }else{
        string1 = string1 + "," + array1[i];
    }
}

console.log("Resulting array: " + string1);
```

You will see this output;
[Console output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW3gw.png)

The last 2 elements will not loop because `i` will be 3 in the next for loop and length will be 2.

The clean solution can be;

```
var array1 = ["A"];
var array2 = ["B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"];
while(array2.length) {
    array1.push(array2.pop());
    if (array2.length) {
        array1.push(array2.shift());
    }
}
console.log("Resulting array: " + array1.join(','));
```